# Brownian bridge expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $X_t=B_t-tB_1$, where $B_t$ represents standard Brownian motion for $0\leq t\leq 1$. For $0\leq s<t\leq 1$, find $$\mathbb{E}(X_s|X_t=1).$$

So, here's what I thought. We have $X_t=1$, so $B_t-tB_1=1$, which means that $B_1=\frac{1}{t}(B_t-1)$. Then, our expression becomes $$\mathbb{E}(B_s-sB_1|B_1=\frac{1}{t}(B_t-1))=\mathbb{E}(B_s|B_1=\frac{1}{t}(B_t-1))-s\mathbb{E}(B_1|B_1=\frac{1}{t}(B_t-1)).$$

The second term is easy to solve, it becomes $-\frac{s}{t}(B_t-1)$. What about the first term? I am suspecting that $\mathbb{E}(B_s|B_1=\frac{1}{t}(B_t-1))=\frac{s}{t}(B_t-1)$ using some kind of binomial, but I can't justify this. Is this approach correct?

Comment: There is a mistake in your proof. That is 
$$E(B_1| \{B_1 =\frac{1}{t}(B_t - 1)\}) = E(B_1| \{B_t - tB_1 = 1\}) \color{red}{\ne}  E(B_1|B_1) = B_1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's decompose
$$X_s=B_s -sB_1 = \left( B_s - \frac{s}{t}B_t \right)+ \frac{s}{t}\left(B_t-tB_1 \right)$$

We have $\left( B_s - \frac{s}{t}B_t \right) = \left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)B_s-\frac{s}{t}(B_t-B_s)$ and $(B_t-tB_1)=(1-t)B_t-t(B_1-B_t)$; so both follow normal distribution. Besides,
\begin{align}Cov( B_s - \frac{s}{t}B_t,B_t-tB_1)& =s-ts-\frac{s}{t}t+\frac{s}{t}t\times t= 0
\end{align}
Then $\left( B_s - \frac{s}{t}B_t \right)$and $\left(B_t-tB_1 \right)$ are independant. We deduce that
$$E(B_s - \frac{s}{t}B_t |B_t-tB_1)=0$$

Hence,
\begin{align}
E(X_s|X_t) &= E\left( \left( B_s - \frac{s}{t}B_t \right)+ \frac{s}{t}\left(B_t-tB_1 \right) |B_t-tB_1\right)\\
&= E\left( B_s - \frac{s}{t}B_t |B_t-tB_1\right)+E\left(\frac{s}{t}\left(B_t-tB_1 \right)|B_t-tB_1\right)\\
&= \frac{s}{t}(B_t-tB_1) \\
&=\frac{s}{t}X_t \\ 
\end{align}
We deduce the particular case
$$E(X_s|X_t = 1) = \frac{s}{t}$$

Comment: thank you! So then, $\mathbb{E}(B_s|B_1=\frac{1}{t}(B_t-1))=sB_1=\frac{s}{t}(B_t-1)$, right? And the final answer is $\mathbb{E}(X_s|X_t=1)=0$. Is this logic correct?

Comment: @david_rios I misunderstood your question. So I modified my first answer. Here above you find the solution. The final answer is
$$E(X_s|X_t) = \frac{s}{t}X_t $$
Hence, 
$$E(X_s|X_t =1 ) =  \frac{s}{t} $$

Comment: Why does the covariance imply independence?

Comment: @david_rios For normal distributions, covariance implies independance

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if the following works? I have left it in term of $B_1$

---

We will assume a weiner process for the brownian motion with $B_{t+1} - B_t \sim \mathcal N(0,1) \forall t$
\begin{align*}
X_t &= B_t-tB_1\\
X_{t-\Delta t} &= B_{t-\Delta t}-(t-\Delta t)B_1\\
X_t - X_{t-\Delta t} &= B_t - B_{t-\Delta t}-\Delta t B_1\\
X_{t-\Delta t} &= X_t + \Delta t B_1 - (B_t - B_{t-\Delta t})\\
\mathbb E [X_{t-\Delta t} |X_t = 1] &= \mathbb E [X_t + \Delta tB_1 - (B_t - B_{t-\Delta t}) |X_t = 1]\\
&= 1 + \Delta t B_1 + \mathbb E (B_t - B_{t-\Delta t}) |X_t = 1]\\
&= 1 + \Delta t B_1 \\
\end{align*}
The last equality is by using the fact that the brownian motion is a weiner process with gaussian increments.
We can rewrite this in terms of $s$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E [X_{s} |X_t = 1] &= 1+(t-s)B_1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I follow the last equality, why can you set $\mathbb{E}(B_t-B_{t-(t-s)}|X_t=1)=0$?

Comment: I've assumed a weiner process where $B_{t+u} - B_t \sim \mathcal N(0,u)$. The expectation is then $\mathbb E[B_t - B_{t-s}] = \mathbb E[\mathcal N(0,t-s)] = 0$. (see 3rd property of brownian motion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process)

Answer (score 1):

$(X_s)_{0\le s\le 1}$ is a Gaussian process with $\Bbb E[X_s] =0$ and $\Bbb E[X_sX_t]=s(1-t)$ for $0\le s\le t\le 1$. Consequently, if we choose $c=s/t$ then the covariance of $X_s-cX_t$ and $X_t$ is $0$, so $X_s-cX_t$ and $X_t$ are independent! With this choice, the conditional distribution of $X_s=(X_s-cX_t) +cX_t$, given that $X_t=x$, is normal with mean $cx$ and variance that of $X_s-cX_t$, namely $s(1-s)+c^2t(1-t)-2cs(1-t) = s(1-s/t)$.